# Why not use Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, stackexchange

I use HTML/CSS since 3 years and I used often Stack Overflow to solve problems about it. Anyway, I'm a beginner in LaTeX world and I discovered LaTeX site in Stack Exchange. I ask me, Why not use Stack Overflow for LaTeX ? LaTeX is a markup language, HTML&CSS too. Can't you create a site for markup language or ask in Stack Overflow?

Comment: (La)TeX is Turing-complete and so can do things that HTML/CSS can't do. We also have a lot of stuff that is 'design-like' so would be out-of-scope on the main site. However, I'm not sure what you are after here: this was addressed when the site was established and it exists, so if you have a (La)TeX question we are here to help.

Comment: Note that there are (La)TeX tags on SO: you can of course post there, though it's likely you'll be pointed back here for a more 'focussed' set of answerers.

Comment: Could you create a Stack Exchange' site for every markup language?

Comment: @JosephWright I know.

Comment: Each proposed site has to have a case made: for (La)TeX that was done and accepted by the 'Powers That Be' and we are grateful for it. As I've noted, (La)TeX is not a markup language (or at least whilst parts of the language are for markup there is more to it).

Comment: I think the same could be said about [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  But once a subcommunity grows large enough they can just split off from the main site.  Also, it is perfectly legal to ask question on TeX/LaTeX on SO, though they will probably be migrated here.

Comment: Anyway, Can I proposal an HTML&CSS site? I know, There is graphic design and stack overflow but HTML&CSS is just to HTML&CSS languagesm

Comment: Yes, anyone can propose a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). You may wish to search there to see if any existing proposals meet your needs.

Comment: StackOverflow is a huge entity I don't want to use -- it's too large (and as I heard users there can be very unfriendly). I think it is better to have a special site for TeX, and a special site for Physics and a special site for Judaism ...

Comment: I hate too Stack Overflow, I ask me anyway why Stackoverflow exist. There are a lot of sites like programmers webmaster etc.

Comment: The thing is, too, that I think the user-base for TeX is maybe more mixed in terms of backgrounds. You can use TeX without knowing anything about programming (about which I know zilch), but SO seems to be aimed at programmers/developers and I wouldn't feel my questions were a good fit there. And TeX has ... idiosyncrasies which set it apart, as I understand it.

Comment: @user111444: I did not say I hate SO ... I just have not used it really.

Answer (score 26):

This is a summary of the comments, so that we can get an answer.  There are a number of reasons why TeX.se exists, and StackOverflow is not the best place for asking TeX related questions.

1. First and foremost, the Stack Exchange model is based on user choices: new sites can be proposed by anyone on the [Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and if the site gains enough visitors, questions and answers, it gets promoted to being a full Stackexchange site.  For TeX.se, this happened almost 5 years ago. The site was proposed, and very quickly there was strong support for it.  Ultimately this is the only answer to your question: there's no need to use Stack Overflow since TeX.se exists and is strongly supported.
2. TeX is not really a markup language, but a fully fledged programming language, albeit one designed with typesetting in mind.
3. StackOverflow is aimed mainly at programmers, but most TeX *users* are not TeX *programmers*, since the goal of TeX is to produce documents, not to program things.  The questions that are addressed here are therefore not mainly about programming, but about how to achieve particular document output.  Of course, since TeX *is* a programming language, we also have programming questions, but these are in some sense the minority.